# NXT for ROS Fuerte?

Tags: nxt, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to use the NXT Package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT) for the Lego Robot under Ros Fuerte? If not, how complicated is it to port it to Fuerte? What has to be done?

BR

Mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55617/nxt-for-ros-fuerte?/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a stack for Electric here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt

and a newer package here, which might be built for fuerte: http://www.ros.org/news/2012/03/new-repository-for-bind-nxt-with-ros-nxt-lejos-pkg.html

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2